# assim que - futuro do subjuntivo vs futuro composto do subjuntivo

Tags: verbos

Qual é a diferença de significado entre as duas frases a seguir?

- Vou estudar assim que eu acabar de comer.
- Vou estudar assim que eu tiver acabado de comer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Futuro do Subjuntivo

O *futuro do subjuntivo simples* indica uma ação que ainda não aconteceu, mas que poderá acontecer. Este tempo também pode indicar eventualidade, possibilidade ou dúvidas.

Normalmente ocorre em orações iniciadas pelas conjunções que indicam tempo ou condição, como, por exemplo, **assim que**, **desde que**, **quando** etc.

- Quando **puderes**, vem visitar-nos.
- Assim que ele se **desocupar**, virá atendê-lo.
- Se ele **puder**, trará o livro.
- Assim que eu **acabar** de comer, vou estudar.

#### Futuro Composto do Subjuntivo

Este tempo verbal exprime o mesmo valor que o *futuro do subjuntivo simples*. Entretanto, neste temos uma locução verbal formada pelo verbo auxiliar *ter* ou *haver* no futuro do subjuntivo *+* verbo principal no particípio.

- Eu te aviso quando eu **tiver terminado** a arrumação.
- Assim que você **tiver terminado** sua leitura, descanse um pouco.
- Assim que eu **tiver acabado** de comer, vou estudar

#### Análise

**Frase #1**

```
 Assim que  eu  acabar  de comer,  vou estudar.
└────┬────┘└─┬┘└──┬───┘└────┬────┘ └────┬────┘
     │       │    │         │           └────── Locução verbal
     │       │    │         └────────────────── Objeto Indireto
     │       │    └──────────────────────────── Verbo Transitivo Indireto (Futuro do Subjuntivo)
     │       └───────────────────────────────── Sujeito simples
     └───────────────────────────────────────── Conjunção subordinada adverbial temporal
```

**Frase #2**

```
 Assim que  eu  tiver acabado  de comer, vou estudar.
└────┬────┘└─┬┘└──────┬──────┘ └───┬───┘ └────┬────┘
     │       │        │            │          └── Locução verbal
     │       │        │            └───────────── Objeto Indireto
     │       │        └────────────────────────── Locução verbal (Futuro do Subjuntivo + Particípio)
     │       └─────────────────────────────────── Sujeito simples
     └─────────────────────────────────────────── Conjunção subordinada adverbial temporal
```

Fonte: https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/6238.md

Comment: Se são formas verbais equivalentes, não existe nenhuma diferença de significado?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista exato. De acordo com Celso Cunha, “O futuro do subjuntivo composto indica um fato futuro como terminado em relação a outro fato futuro”. Entretanto, o sentido da frase não muda. Na sua primeira oração, eu comerei e depois estudarei; na segunda, eu comerei e depois estudarei.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta curta e direta à pergunta **"diferença em significado"**:

> - não há diferença semântica. O significado é exatamente o mesmo.